# Show the JNLP java webstart console programatically

Tags: java, java-web-start

In the control panel under `Java`, there is an `Advanced` option to `Show console`...  With this enabled, an additional window launches when my app launches.  The window is titled `Java Console - MyApp Name`.

Is there a way to launch this console window programmatically?  Rather than require the user to enable this feature, I would like to make the window available on request from the application.

Is the console a feature of Java WebStart?  I do not see an API call for the console in the webstart [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/index.html).  If I look elsewhere, I just see many references to the System console object which has nothing to do with the console window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such default 'application console' attached to JWS apps.